# I can't to send post request via xhr

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I want to send number to the file and to receive data from file. 
In file loader.php I do this answer "echo json_encode($_REQUEST)" for request, to make sure to come to file or not, but what i will see empty array. Help me, pls. I don't know what's wrong ?

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
var inProgress = false;

var startFrom = 10;

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    var scrollHeight = Math.max(
        document.body.scrollHeight, document.documentElement.scrollHeight,
        document.body.offsetHeight, document.documentElement.offsetHeight,
        document.body.clientHeight, document.documentElement.clientHeight
    );

    if(window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight >= scrollHeight - 200 && 
!inProgress) {


        let request = obj => {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.open(obj.method || "GET", obj.url);
                if (obj.headers) {
                    Object.keys(obj.headers).forEach(key => {
                        xhr.setRequestHeader(key, obj.headers[key]);
                    });
                }

                xhr.onload = () => {
                    if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 300) {
                        resolve(xhr.response);
                    } else {
                        reject(xhr.statusText);
                    }
                };
                xhr.onerror = () => reject(xhr.statusText);
                xhr.send(obj.body);
            });
        };

        request({url: "/proc-service/loader.php", method: "POST", body: "1"})
            .then(data => {
                let tasks = JSON.parse(data);
                console.log(tasks);
                let html = "";
                tasks.forEach(task => {
                    html +=
                        "<li id=\"content__list\">" +
                        "<span>" + task.id + "</span> " +
                        "<span>" + task.title + "</span>" +
                        "</li>";
                });
                document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = html;
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });

    }
});
});
```

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?

Comment: @jdv I want to send data to the file loader.php, but xhr doesn't do that.

Comment: You are only sending the value 1, you need to format the data in a way that is recognized and is parseable from php, like a query string `variablename=1` . Otherwise you will need to read the raw input from `php://input`

Comment: XHR does send data. If it is a POST request you need to set the proper request header for `Content-Type` and place the payload data in the body of the request. If it's a GET request you can just place GET arguments in the URL of the request

Comment: @JayBlanchard I don't have any errors and reported. The file loader.php gives me empty array. I can send "echo json_encode("smth")"; and I I will see the answer came "smth".

Comment: @FAST it is still unclear what you exactly want to do. The assumption is that you have some endpoint you want to connect to and send/recv data that is in a file somewhere. But it is not clear at all that this is what you are doing.

Comment: @jdv I want to send some data to the file loader.php and then I want to receive some data form loader.php. How I can do that ?